# how to uniquely identify a json string?

Tags: json, string, hashcode

I need to identify uniqueness of json strings for my use case. For this purpose I am using the hashcode of the string. It is working fine if the json string is same but in case the json strings are unequal there is possibility of collision. Can someone please suggest how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Compare the chars and return `false` if any of them don't match? I am having a hard time understanding your scenario. (Or just use your preferred language's `String` `equals` function.)

Comment: I need to put json messages in hazelcast cache and cache only allows unique values as a key. I need to create cache keys out of various json strings given to me. So basically I need to form cache key from json message like field1_field2_field3_hashcode where hashcode is calculated based on all the values of json(field1,field2,field3....).Since hashcode can be same for different json strings as well, Is there anyway to achieve this.